# Estimating shared parameter from negative binomial sample

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, negative-binomial-distribution

I came across a problem and I think it is 
unsolvable, but I would like to make sure that this is the case.

Let consider a sample:
$$
X_1, X_2, ... X_n \sim NB(r_i, p).
$$
Therefore I know that observations share $p$ parameter, but each observation $X_i$ can have a different $r_i$. I do not know anything about $r_i$. Is it possible to estimate the common parameter $p$? I do not need to estimate $r_i$.

I tried to find maximum likelihood estimator (forgetting that $r_i$ differs through the sample) and retrieve $p$, but it gives wrong result.

Here I assume that $p=0.2$.

```
r <- rgamma(1000, 3,0.1)
x <- sapply(r, function(x) rnbinom(1, size=x, p=0.2))

library(MASS)
par.nb<- fitdistr(x, "negative binomial")
par.nb$estimate

size <- par.nb$estimate[1]
mu <- par.nb$estimate[2]

p_est <-size/(mu+size)
p_est
```

But $p\_est = 0.02085524$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fitdistr` finds you an estimate for $r$ and $p$ as if all the data is sampled from the same distribution. I you try to find an MLE for $p$ assuming all $r_i$ are different, you'll have $$\hat p = \frac{\sum x_i}{\sum (x_i+r_i)}$$

However, you also don't know $r_i$. If you try to take derivative wrt $r_i$, you'll encounter something [like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,successes%20(denoted%20r)%20occurs.) $$\psi(x_i+r_i)-\psi(r_i)+\log\left({r_i \over {r_i+x_i}}\right)=0$$
where $\psi(x)$ is [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) function. As wikipedia page says, there is no closed form solution exist. Moreover, for estimating $r_i$, you're using only one sample. But, as [cited](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/1467-842X.00075) in the wiki page:

> The maximum likelihood estimator only exists for samples for which the sample variance is larger than the sample mean.

When $n=1$, the sample variance is $0$, so we can't actually estimate $r_i$. So, a MLE is not possible.

Comment: When $n=1$ the sample variance is undefined rather than equal to 0.

Comment: It is true that MLE is not possible, but the quote you show is incorrect. When the sample variance is equal or smaller than the sample mean, the MLE does of $r$ does exist but it is infinite. The specific estimator of the cited paper might not be computable in such cases, but the likelikhood can still be maximized and the MLE of $r$ is $\infty$. In other words the MLE of the dispersion parameter $\phi=1/r$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously impossible to estimate $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ and $p$ because that is $n+1$ parameters and you have only $n$ data points from which to estimate them.
It is impossible to estimate $n+1$ independent parameters from $n$ data values.

You can however estimate $p$ if the $r_i$ are known or if you at least know $\bar r=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n r_i$.
In the latter case, the sample mean $\bar x$ would be an unbiased estimator of
$$\frac{\bar r p}{1-p}$$
so
$$\hat p=\frac{\exp(\bar x/r)}{1+\exp(\bar x/r)}$$
is a consistent estimator of $p$.

This estimator $\hat p$ is somewhat inefficient however if the $r_i$ are very different.
If you did know the values of $r_i$ then a more efficient estimator of $p$ would be possible.